# Using VBA to paste a range containing Vlookups as value, returns the first value repeated

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

First time posting and relatively new to VBA.

In Column A, I have a list of Invoice #s and Column B is a vlookup that returns which sales channel originated the Invoice (Corporate, Retail, etc.).  I'm trying to write a VBA macro that will copy and paste those values into another worksheet.  When I do, it pastes the value from the first vlookup into all the rows.(row A works without any problem)  Any ideas why?

```
'Finds Last Row of Raw Data
With WB1
Worksheets("Raw Data").Select
    lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

'Copy and Paste Department info 
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("GF1:GF" & lRow).Copy
Worksheets("DataForReport").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

This is a small portion of a larger macro I'm working on.  If you need more of the code please let me know and I can post a larger portion of it.  Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: "Column B is a vlookup" - You aren't copying from column B - you are copying from column GF.  Also, why do you have a `With WB1` block and then never use the `With` object anywhere within the block?

Answer (score 0):

Isnt your source in two columns ?

You are only copying column "GF" : `Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("GF1:GF" & lRow).Copy`

And pasting it to : `Worksheets("DataForReport").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

What is you source data range ? GF1:GG & lRow ?

Your "With WB1 ... End with" seems useless in that code.

Try :

```
'Finds Last Row of Raw Data
    lRow = Worksheets("Raw Data").usedrange.specialcells(xlcelltypelastcell).row
'Copy and Paste Department info 
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("GF1:GG" & lRow).Copy
    Worksheets("DataForReport").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

And adapt ranges to your needs.